# Compile DXA Templating 2.2.3 for SDL Tridion 8.5

Tags: dxa, web8.5, templating, dxa2.2

We have a SDL Tridion 8.5 installation with DXA 2.0.3.
Now we want to migrate to DXA 2.2.3 as previous step to migrate SDL Tridion to 9.5.

In the templating part, we did some extensions that we want to maintain in DXA Templating 2.2.3. But when we try to compile, it's failing because it's expecting SDL dlls of 9.X version instead of dlls of 8.5. All the part related to Regions doesn't exist in SDL 8.5.

We saw in the documentation that the process to import to SDL determines how to manage Regions depending on SDL version.

It means that we could compile DXA templating + our extensions with SDL 9.X libraries and upload it to SDL Tridion 8.5 using the import.ps script?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DXA 2.2 TBBs for Web 8.5 are effectively “hotfixed” DXA 2.0 TBBs.
The source code for these TBBs is on the `release/2.0` branch in GitHub: https://github.com/sdl/dxa-content-management/tree/release/2.0

The version detection logic in the `cms-import.ps1` PowerShell script determines whether the CMS is 8.5 or 9.x and based on that selects the Web 8.5 or Sites 9 CMS packages (from the DXA distribution).

If you want the script to pick up your own customized CMS package, ypu would have to overwrite the appropriate CMS package(s) from the DXA distribution.